# How to implement the calendar layout logic in ASP.NET and C# with MS SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core

[image: I want to implement this layout In C#]

I have this project at school and I have created a project with homePage, member signUp, member Login, member profile, and Admin Login pages I want to implement this layout on my homepage when the user is logged in and be able to select dates when an employee is working from home should choose a date and insert into a database for the employer to see who is working from home on this specific date or day.[image: The picture below is my Home page currently I want to change it to the layout with a calendar]

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here

Comment: I don't see a question, maybe you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) again

Comment: I want to implement the layout on the sketch I need help with making this layout actually the start-up point splitting screens into three parts as shown on the sketch (The Employees list on the left, Calendar on the center, and Days on the right) and actually using a calendar in ASP.NET Web app with labels of the events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if we break this down?

We need a listbox on the left side to display the Employee's

So, drop in a listbox, say like this:

```
        <div style="float:left">
            <asp:ListBox ID="lstEmployee" runat="server" 
                DataValueField="ID"
                DataTextField="EmpName" Height="270px" Width="125px" 
                AutoPostBack="True" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            </asp:ListBox>
        </div>
```

And our code to load is thus this:

```
    DateTime dtStart, dtEnd;    // start and end of this month
    DateTime CalStart, CalEnd;  // start and end of the whole cal display

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadEmployee();
            LoadCal();
        }
    }

    void LoadEmployee()
    {
        // load up employee listbox
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT ID,(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as EmpName " +
          "FROM Employee ORDER BY FirstName");

        lstEmployee.DataSource = MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        lstEmployee.DataBind();
    }
```

And now we have this:

[image]

Ok, now we need a calendar. Hum, ok, looking at outlook, we see that we need 6 rows of a "thing".

I think a simple Listview, and for each row (6 of them), we need a data table, with 1-7 days of data.

So, a simple list view, one row - but we spit out 6 of them.

and we want the calendar to be clickable, so each day will be a button - a LinkButton should work fine.

So, a list view could be like this:

```
        <div style="float:left;margin-left:25px">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound1"  >
            <ItemTemplate>
              <tr id="OneRow" runat="server"> 
                 <td>
                    <asp:Linkbutton ID="L1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Sun", "{0:dd}") %>'
                    bDate = '<%# Eval("Sun") %>' OnClick="L1_Click"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Linkbutton ID="L2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Mon", "{0:dd}") %>' 
                     bDate = '<%# Eval("Mon") %>' OnClick="L1_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Linkbutton ID="L3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tue", "{0:dd}") %>' 
                    bDate = '<%# Eval("Tue") %>' OnClick="L1_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Linkbutton ID="L4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Wed", "{0:dd}") %>'
                    bDate = '<%# Eval("Wed") %>' OnClick="L1_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Linkbutton ID="L5" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Thu", "{0:dd}") %>'
                    bDate = '<%# Eval("Thu") %>' OnClick="L1_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Linkbutton ID="L6" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fri", "{0:dd}") %>'
                    bDate = '<%# Eval("Fri") %>' OnClick="L1_Click" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Linkbutton ID="L7" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Sat", "{0:dd}") %>'
                    bDate = '<%# Eval("Sat") %>' OnClick="L1_Click" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                <tr runat="server" style="">
                    <th runat="server" style="text-align:center" >Sun</th>
                    <th runat="server" style="text-align:center">Mon</th>
                    <th runat="server" style="text-align:center">Tue</th>
                    <th runat="server" style="text-align:center">Wed</th>
                    <th runat="server" style="text-align:center">Thr</th>
                    <th runat="server" style="text-align:center">Fri</th>
                    <th runat="server" style="text-align:center">Sat</th>
                </tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Not a lot of markup.

Now, we need to load up the data, so we have this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadEmployee();
            LoadCal();
        }
    }
```

And the code to load up the calendar? A data table of 6 rows, and 7 columns, say like this code:

```
    void LoadCal()
    {
        SetupDates();

        DataTable OneMonth = new DataTable();
        // add heading colums to table (Sun->Sat)
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            DateTime d = CalStart.AddDays(i);
            string strCol = d.ToString("ddd"); // gets day of week as text (sun->sat)
            OneMonth.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(strCol, typeof(DateTime)));
        }

        DateTime dtPtr = CalStart;   // start a simple date counter - upper left
        // add 6 rows for calendar
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            DataRow OneRow = OneMonth.Rows.Add();
            for (int wDay = 0; wDay <= 6; wDay++) // put date in each colum 1 - 7
            {
                OneRow[wDay] = dtPtr;   // shove date into cal square
                dtPtr = DateAndTime.DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, dtPtr);
            }
            ListView1.DataSource = OneMonth;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And we now have this:

[image]

Now, I did want to "gray" out the dates off this month, so in the Listview databound event (a great event for formatting grids or listview), then I put in this code

If the date ptr is outside of this month, we grey out the linkbutton.

so, this:

```
    protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound1(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            ListViewDataItem lvRow = e.Item as ListViewDataItem;
            for (int MyDay = 1; MyDay <= 7;MyDay++)
            {
                LinkButton LDate = lvRow.FindControl("L" + MyDay) as LinkButton;
                DateTime BoxDate =  Convert.ToDateTime(LDate.Attributes["bDate"]);
                if ( (BoxDate < dtStart) | (BoxDate > dtEnd)) 
                    LDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;

                // this sets the size for ALL squares 
                LDate.Attributes.Add("style", "float:right;height:70px;width:60px;text-align:right");
            }
        }
    }
```

Ok, so now we have to add some code to highlight a square if this is a work at home date.

We have this data table:

[image]

So, after we load the Grid, then we click on a list view item.

That code is this:

```
    protected void lstEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int EmployeeID = 0;
        EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(lstEmployee.SelectedValue);
        ShowOffDays(EmployeeID);
    }
```

So, we need a routine to now display (highlight) any record in the table based on employee id and the given date.

So this:

```
    void ShowOffDays(int EmpID)
    {
        SetupDates();

        var cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(
            "SELECT * FROM AtHome WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpID " +
            "AND AtHomeDate BETWEEN @dtSTart AND @dtEnd");

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EmpID;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dtStart", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtStart;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@dtEnd", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtEnd;

        DataTable rstAtHome = new DataTable();
        rstAtHome = MyRstP(cmdSQL);

        DateTime dtPtr = CalStart;
        for(int i = 0;i<=5;i++)
        {
            ListViewItem lvRow = ListView1.Items[i];
            for (int wDay = 1;wDay <= 7;wDay++)
            {
                if ((dtPtr >= dtStart) & (dtPtr <= dtEnd))   // only highlit this month
                {
                    LinkButton LDate = lvRow.FindControl("L" + wDay) as LinkButton;
                    DataRow[] tView = rstAtHome.Select("AtHomeDate = #" + dtPtr + "#");
                    if (tView.Length == 0)
                        // no at home date
                        LDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                    else
                        // found a date - blue the square0
                        LDate.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
                }
                dtPtr = DateAndTime.DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, dtPtr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, that was a bit of code - but not too bad.

So, now we get this:

[image]

Ok, so now we need a click event for the square. If you click a empty square, we add a single row to the table, and if already highliged, we delete it.

So, that click event can be this:

```
    protected void L1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = sender as LinkButton;
        DateTime dtDateV = Convert.ToDateTime(btn.Attributes["bDate"]);
        int EmpID = Convert.ToInt32(lstEmployee.SelectedItem.Value);

        DataTable rstDayOff = new DataTable();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (var cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(
                "SELECT * FROM AtHome WHERE EmployeeID = @EmpID " +
                "AND AtHomeDate = @Date", conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = EmpID;
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dtDateV;
                conn.Open();
                rstDayOff.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                if (rstDayOff.Rows.Count == 0 )
                {
                    // add this day off to table
                    DataRow OneDay = rstDayOff.Rows.Add();
                    OneDay["EmployeeID"] = EmpID;
                    OneDay["AtHomeDate"] = dtDateV;
                    btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
                }
                else
                {
                    // delete the at home day
                    rstDayOff.Rows[0].Delete();
                    btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                }
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                SqlCommandBuilder daU = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(rstDayOff);
            }
        }
    }
```

Not bad! So, now you can click to highlight, or un-highlight a day. (it toggles the given square).

So, above should give you some ideas.

And the two helper routines I used was to get a data table.
And the other to setup the dates.

These:

```
    void SetupDates()
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;

        dtStart = DateAndTime.DateSerial(DateAndTime.Year(dt), DateAndTime.Month(dt), 1);
        int DaysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateAndTime.Year(dt),DateAndTime.Month(dt));

        // end of month = DaysInmonth less one
        dtEnd = DateAndTime.DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, DaysInMonth - 1, dtStart);

        // now with date end/start - get display start/end (subtract day of week)

        CalStart = DateAndTime.DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1 - (DateAndTime.Weekday(dtStart)), dtStart);
        CalEnd = DateAndTime.DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 41, CalStart);

    }
```

and

```
    DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
            cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

So, it was a bit of code, but breaking down each part - into smaller bits and sizes? It was not really that hard.

## Edit: the connection string

Well, the connection string is generally placed in the web.config file. However you can get visual studio to do that for you and it tends to be a whole lot easier.

So, from Visual studio, go project->"my project settings".

Say like this:

[image]

So, for things like maybe the welcome message, company name, perhaps to use some tax rate, or a bunch of typical settings that just about any and every applcation has?

Well, you can use the settings tab from above. so, say like this:

[image]

So, in above, I have My Cool Company name, and in code I can thus reference that setting. And note how I have multiple conneciton strings.

Using the above is nice, since if you choose to add a connection string, it not only means ONE PLACE in your whole application, but you can use the connection string builder to help you out.

Say, like this:

[image]

when you click on the [...], then you get this:

[image]

so, you get the connection wizard, and that makes setting up a connection a whole lot less hassile.

So, now in code, to get that string, you can use this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
```

Now, at the end of the day, if you go look at web.config, you see the settings in web.config, but that can be extra work, so using the above project settings is a just a great handy place to use and place all of the many settings you will have in any typical applcation.

Comment: Okay thank you so much for this this is good I hope we can have a chat because I will need a bit more help with the database architecture of this system and help me learn more to become an expert in ASP.NET. The help i really need is the architecture of my database fields i have a few but i want to make sure i capture all the data needed

Comment: Not anything more required. We have a simple table of employees, and then I show the other simple table of at home dates. The code above us more than enough. If you click on a calendar square then we add row to at home table and then color that date square blue. Don't see anything more required. But not interested in doing your cooking or cleaning for you, and time better spent here as opposed to helping only you. Why would I do that and remove my sharing with the community here and take that away just for you alone? Why? You are free to ask more here in posts - we help many people as result

Comment: Apologies for that I have one more question is this example you gave me for ASP.NET Core or MVC

Comment: Asp.net - and web forms. So it's neither core and it's not MVC.  But the concept and approach is going to be much the same. And it's not core vs non core. You can build as MVC without core, or use core with MVC. Core is simply a newer version of.net that comes after regular 4.8. but MVC approach can be used with older.net and MVC, or you can use newer .net core and MVC. But this example was webforms, and that can't be used with .net core.

Comment: Okay thank you very much i have coded all the methods and removed the content on my HomePage whil testing the only thing that appeared was the list of employees but with empty data only the listBox. I also wanted to ask about the Connection String, actually if you could explain how you used the connection string to access the database  becuase i just declared the String (ConnectionString= ''******") and then parsed it on the using (SqlCommand con = new SqlCommand(ConnectionString) line that the method i learned at school

Comment: See my edit and part two I added to above post - I explain how I setup and used that connection string.

Comment: Great, now I have an issue the calendar is not displaying at first it was because some events were not defined on the homepage. aspx.cs but i have defined all the methods required still it doesn't display please help me on this one. When i go to design i only see days of the week and below it the "itemDataBound" on every row and column

Comment: Well, in design mode you not going to see the calendar, but when you run the code, you should see a calendar on a page. I would create a blank new test page - drop in that list view, and let it run the code that fills out the calendar. Remember, that calendar does not even need a database connection to display. All it does is create a data table with 6 rows - and 7 columns with the date for each day of the week. so the calendar can display and run - even without any database connection. I would play with, and try the calendar on a brand new separate test page until you get it working.

Comment: I think there is an undefined method in my class actually missing method which is "ListVIew1_SelectedIndexChanged" because i now get a compile error : (Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'homepage_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged' and no accessible extension method 'ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'homepage_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?))

Comment: Well, we want to break this down into steps. You want to get your list box working. Obviosity the "events" for the listbox are not setup. So, bring up the property sheet for the listbox, click on the lighting bolt and you see the events for the listbox. (so, go into list box markup and remove the selected index changed markup, and then in that property sheet double click on the selected index changed event - and that code stub will be created in the code behind. So, we not at the point to deal with the listview, but are still working on the listbox part of this problem.

Comment: Okay Now the ListBox is loaded the names from the database are now being retrieved to the ListBox next is for me to deal with the calendar can you help me move foward to the calendar

Comment: The list view part should work, and in fact can work without any database at all. You just need to take the sample code posted and make sure the list view events posted above are wired up. It was assumed that say dropping a text box or say a list view onto a page was a basic skill set you have. So with posted list view markup you need to add the code posted for the lv. Not at clear which part or code for the lv is not working, but to debug such code we will need significantly more details